# Newbie here: how do I apply a patch to the source of a python package in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, patch, pygraphviz

I am trying to install Pygraphviz for Python 3.5 x86 under Windows 7 x64
After trying to install I am getting the error indicated here

https://github.com/Kagami/pygraphviz/commit/fe442dc16accb629c3feaf157af75f67ccabbd6e

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo
 /INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\lib\debug\lib" /L
IBPATH:C:\winpy\python-3.4.3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\winpy\python-3.4.3\PCbuild cgraph.
lib cdt.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__graphviz build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\pygraphviz/gra
phviz_wrap.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.4\pygraphviz\_graphviz.pyd /IMPLIB:build\t
emp.win32-3.4\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-3.
4\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.lib and ob
ject build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\pygraphviz\_graphviz.exp
graphviz_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyIOBase_Type ref
erenced in function __wrap_agread
build\lib.win32-3.4\pygraphviz\_graphviz.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
 externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\
link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

At the bottom of that thread there is a reference to a patch that has to be applied to the pygraphviz package and then I guess I will have to install it from source

**My question is: How do I use patch in Windows ?**

Update: I have downloaded patch for windows and the patch file 
I have put them in the same folder with the source package -see the picture

[image]

Now I need the find the right command line switches for this
A dry run (**patch --dry-run < fixpygraphviz.patch**   ) gives me this error

```
can't find file to patch at input line 16
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From fe442dc16accb629c3feaf157af75f67ccabbd6e Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Kagami Hiiragi <kagami@genshiken.org>
|Date: Mon, 4 Aug 2014 21:57:54 +0400
|Subject: [PATCH] Workaround for PyIOBase_Type for Python3 on win
|
|Fixes #16
|---
| pygraphviz/graphviz.i      | 23 +++++++++++++++++++++--
| pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c | 24 +++++++++++++++++++++---
| 2 files changed, 42 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
|
|diff --git a/pygraphviz/graphviz.i b/pygraphviz/graphviz.i
|index 8c06805..55e5b6d 100644
|--- a/pygraphviz/graphviz.i
|+++ b/pygraphviz/graphviz.i
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Answer (score 0):

patch -px -i patchfilename

where x indicates how many levels of folders to skip from the path indicated in the patch file. In my case it was p1 which meant that patch should look for "folder/filename" and not for "folder/folder/filename" as indicated in the patch file.